# How to match files end not with regex

Tags: regex, string, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to filter all files not ending with, for instance `mp3` or `wv`.
I have tried to use something like this  `^.*(?<![mp3|wv])$` but this expression doesn't work.
Please help to create valid expression.

Comment: What flavour of regular expressions are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Negative Lookahead instead.

```
^(?!.*(?:mp3|wv)$).*
```

Comment: Good but I think also Casimir et Hippolyte's answer is an elegant way!

Answer (score 3):

Since a lookbehind is a zero-width assertion, you can write:

```
^.*(?<!mp3)(?<!wv)$
```

or better ($ is a zero-width assertion too):

```
^.*$(?<!mp3)(?<!wv)
```

if your regex flavor allows it (PCRE, Java), you can use an alternation:

```
^.*$(?<!mp3|wv)
```

Note: if your goal is only to know if a string doesn't end with "vw" or "mp3", you can test if `(?:mp3|wv)$` is false.